# How to render two components inside a .md file for styleguidist in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-styleguidist

I am trying to create a styleguide with custom components. I need to be able to insert components inside of each other and not sure how to do that inside of the .md file. I have a list and list items. I want to display the list items inside of the list. Getting this error in the styleguidist display. Here are some good examples but none that illustrate what I am trying to accomplish -- https://github.com/styleguidist/react-styleguidist/tree/master/examples/basic/src/components

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token (3:0)
>   1 : import ListItem from './ListItem'
>   2 : 
>   3 :

List.tsx

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import './List.css'

    export interface IListProps {
      /** Type of button to display */
      font: string;
      disabled: boolean;
      mtmClass: string;
      link: boolean;
    }

    class List extends Component<IListProps> {
      render() {
        const { children } = this.props
        return <ul className={'mtm-list'}>{children}</ul>
      }
    }

    export default List
```

List.md

````
    ```js
    import ListItem from './ListItem'

    <List>
       <ListItem> 
           Content in a List
       </ListItem>
    </List>
````

ListItem.tsx

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import './List.css'

    export interface IListItemProps {
      /** Type of button to display */
      font: string;
      disabled: boolean;
      mtmClass: string;
      link: boolean;
    }

    class ListItem extends Component<IListItemProps> {
      render() {
        const { children } = this.props
        return <li className={'mtm-list-item'}>{children}</li>
      }
    }

    export default ListItem
```

Comment: Are you trying to run javascript stored in a markdown file? I'm not sure you'll find an easy solution to do so. I suggest rendering your content naturally as HTML and then using an HTML to markdown converter.

Comment: I recommend trying out .mdx file types (think .jsx in an markdown file) - https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx

Comment: Updated my post. Added a reference for the reason as to why I'm using md files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to change the .md to this format and it worked, specifically adding the semicolon.

````
```jsx
import React from 'react'
import Button from 'rsg-example/components/Button'
import Placeholder from 'rsg-example/components/Placeholder'
;<Button>
  <Placeholder />
</Button>
```
````

Comment: Yes you need semicolon.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [MDX](https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx) helpful.

"MDX is an authorable format that lets you seamlessly write JSX in your Markdown documents"

```sh
yarn add mdx.macro
```

rename List.md to List.mdx and now you can something like this

```js
    import ListItem from './ListItem'
#Header
    <List>
       <ListItem> 
           *content*
       </ListItem>
    </List>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't compatible with Styleguidist